# Writing a more compact if statement in Python

Tags: python, if-statement

I have been working on a calculator in Python. There is nothing wrong with the calculator, but I would like to make part of the code in it more optimized/shortened.

Here is the code that I want optimized/shortened:

```
   #In this code i check to see if they have entered a valid option in my calculator
   option = int(input("Option: "))
   if option != 0:
      if option != 1:
         if option != 2:
             if option != 3:
                if option != 4:
                   print("Please enter a valid choice")
                   #As you can see it needs to check 5 numbers
```

if you can figure out a way to shorten the code above it would be MUCH appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is one more way to write it:

```
if not 0 <= option <= 4:
   print("Not a valid choice")
```

Answer (score 5):

If you have all your options in a list this would be the quickest and easiest way.

```
if option not in [1,2,3,4]:
   print("Not a valid choice")
```

Comment: You should avoid this. Explained in Alex Gaynor talk on the PyCon 2014: Fast Python, Slow Python (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7eeEf_rAJds). if not((option==1) or (option==2) or (option==3) or (option==4)) is more efficient.

Answer (score 4):

Use `and` instead of multiple `if`

```
if option != 0 and option != 1 and option != 2 and option != 3 and option != 4:
```

or you may use `not` and `in` operator together.

```
>>> if option not in xrange(0, 5):
        something....
```

Comment: `xrange` and `range` are exclusive on the last entry; if you want to replicate the behavior exactly, you'd need `xrange(0, 5)`.

Answer (score 4):

```
if option < 0 or option > 4:
    print("Please enter a valid choice")
```

is the easiest and can be changed quickly if the numbering of your options changes.

Answer (score 1):

```python
value = int(input("Value?: "))

while value not in range(0,5):
    print "Yaba daba doo!"
    if value not in range(0,5):
        print "Scoobie doo!"
        break
else:
    print "What to doo!? :p"
```

**Bibliography:**
[Yabba Dabba Doo! - YouTube](http://youtu.be/qpGx4foRdPw)
[Scooby Doo Theme Song - YouTube](http://youtu.be/0_C2HJvtRDY)